# Php DOMDocument set element value by name

Tags: php, dom

I've got an element by name attribute in Php using a DOMDocument (I do not want to use id) but how can I then set it's textContent and save to the dom object?

So far I have the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
  $element_name = $element->getAttribute("name");
  if($element_name == 'mytextareaname') {
    $element->textContent = "Some text content";
  }
}
$html_with_values = $dom->saveHTML();
```

But the values are not saved, because I probably need to reference the $dom object when saving rather than $element. How can I do that, can I add a key to the foreach and use that?

Comment: Your syntax should be works. Are you sure that `if` condition is respected?

Comment: Yes, I've tested that the if statement is processed but I now see that $element->textContent not being set because echo $element->textContent immediately after setting the value returns nothing.

Comment: Can you load your real HTML?

Comment: $dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea')->item(0)->nodeValue = "Some text content" works.
(the real html is too long for here)
Seems I need to use nodeValue to set textContent because $element->nodeValue = "Some text content" works.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the dom element's textContent for a textarea did not work, but setting it's nodeValue set both nodeValue and textContent.